# find the matrix of $D$ a relative to this basis $ (-\cos x, \sin x).$

Tags: linear-algebra

let $D: V\to V$ be the differentiation operator. find the matrix of $D$ a relative to this  basis $ (-\cos x, \sin x).$

My attempt:

$D(-\cos x)=\sin x=0. \cos x  + 1.\sin x $

$D(\sin x)=\cos x = 1.\cos x + 0 .\sin x$

Therefore the matrix  representing the differential operator  $D$ a relative to this basis $(-\cos x ,\sin x)$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 1& 0 \end{bmatrix} ^T=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 1& 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Is its true ?

Comment: You have a sign error. The basis contains $-\cos x$, not $\cos x$. Therefore $D(\sin x)=-1.(-\cos x)+0.\sin x$

Comment: im not getting @Andrei  differention of $\cos x$ is$ -\sin x $  so $ - \times - = +ve$

Comment: okss @Andrei now got its thanks u

Comment: Note that your matrix $M$ satisfies $M^2 = I$, but the differentiation operator does not satisfy this for the given basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D(\sin x) = \cos x = -(-\cos x)$, as the basis element is $-\cos x$ not $\cos x$. This does not affect the first computation. So the matrix is then $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.